# How IPv6 headers handle next headers?

Tags: networking, ipv6

I was reading that IPv6 headers have a fixed size, but then there is a field for next header also present in the header, which can specify the next header.

Even if the main header is being transmitted first and then the later ones than how is this better compared to the variable size in IPv4. Also how is the main header keeping a track of the next headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed header size is for simplicity and speed. Having the basics of source, dest, and hop limit in fixed locations allows for fast forwarding; acceleration of bit operations, possibly in hardware ASICs, is easier with constant offsets.

Next header allows for encapsulation of either the upper protocol payload (TCP) or an IPv6 header extension via the same mechanism. [See examples in RFC8200.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8200#section-4) Essentially, this is a "linked list" of headers, each pointing to the next, and all fitting in the payload size.

This scheme allows fancy header features to be optional. A packet capture on my desktop shows several examples of no extension headers, the next header is direct to TCP.